# Thrift - combine reading http and raw processing

Tags: javascript, http, thrift

I'm looking at [Thrift's tutorial example](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java). I'm trying to create a server that processes raw thrift requests (raw) and javascript requests (http).

The java server reads directly from the socket - new TServerSocket(9090) - processing the request using thrift's protocol.

The javascript example, though, requires a http server (Httpd.java). I found it in the downloaded sources. See below.

Both process the incoming bytes differently. **How can I combine both processing?** Having the fast thrift raw processing, combined with http processing for reading browser requests?

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.MethodNotSupportedException;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentProducer;
import org.apache.http.entity.EntityTemplate;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.NoConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandlerRegistry;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.thrift.TProcessor;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TMemoryBuffer;

// Generated code
import tutorial.*;
import shared.*;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Basic, yet fully functional and spec compliant, HTTP/1.1 file server.
 * <p>
 * Please note the purpose of this application is demonstrate the usage of
 * HttpCore APIs. It is NOT intended to demonstrate the most efficient way of
 * building an HTTP file server.
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Httpd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Please specify document root directory");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Thread t = new RequestListenerThread(8088, args[0]);
        t.setDaemon(false);
        t.start();
    }

    static class HttpFileHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

        private final String docRoot;

        public HttpFileHandler(final String docRoot) {
            super();
            this.docRoot = docRoot;
        }

        public void handle(final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

            String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
            if (!method.equals("GET") && !method.equals("HEAD") && !method.equals("POST")) {
                throw new MethodNotSupportedException(method + " method not supported");
            }
            String target = request.getRequestLine().getUri();

            if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest && target.equals("/thrift/service/tutorial/")) {
                HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
                byte[] entityContent = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                System.out.println("Incoming content: " + new String(entityContent));

                final String output = this.thriftRequest(entityContent);

                System.out.println("Outgoing content: "+output);

                EntityTemplate body = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {

                    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
                        writer.write(output);
                        writer.flush();
                    }

                });
                body.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setEntity(body);
            } else {
                final File file = new File(this.docRoot, URLDecoder.decode(target, "UTF-8"));
                if (!file.exists()) {

                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
                    EntityTemplate body = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {

                        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
                            writer.write("<html><body><h1>");
                            writer.write("File ");
                            writer.write(file.getPath());
                            writer.write(" not found");
                            writer.write("</h1></body></html>");
                            writer.flush();
                        }

                    });
                    body.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setEntity(body);
                    System.out.println("File " + file.getPath() + " not found");

                } else if (!file.canRead() || file.isDirectory()) {

                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                    EntityTemplate body = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {

                        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
                            writer.write("<html><body><h1>");
                            writer.write("Access denied");
                            writer.write("</h1></body></html>");
                            writer.flush();
                        }

                    });
                    body.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setEntity(body);
                    System.out.println("Cannot read file " + file.getPath());

                } else {

                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                    FileEntity body = new FileEntity(file, "text/html");
                    response.setEntity(body);
                    System.out.println("Serving file " + file.getPath());

                }
            }
        }

        private String thriftRequest(byte[] input){
            try{

                //Input
                TMemoryBuffer inbuffer = new TMemoryBuffer(input.length);           
                inbuffer.write(input);              
                TProtocol  inprotocol   = new TJSONProtocol(inbuffer);                   

                //Output
                TMemoryBuffer outbuffer = new TMemoryBuffer(100);           
                TProtocol outprotocol   = new TJSONProtocol(outbuffer);

                TProcessor processor = new Calculator.Processor(new CalculatorHandler());      
                processor.process(inprotocol, outprotocol);

                byte[] output = new byte[outbuffer.length()];
                outbuffer.readAll(output, 0, output.length);

                return new String(output,"UTF-8");
            }catch(Throwable t){
                return "Error:"+t.getMessage();
            }


        }

    }

    static class RequestListenerThread extends Thread {

        private final ServerSocket serversocket;
        private final HttpParams params;
        private final HttpService httpService;

        public RequestListenerThread(int port, final String docroot) throws IOException {
            this.serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.params = new BasicHttpParams();
            this.params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 1000).setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 8 * 1024)
                    .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false).setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.ORIGIN_SERVER, "HttpComponents/1.1");

            // Set up the HTTP protocol processor
            HttpProcessor httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();

            // Set up request handlers
            HttpRequestHandlerRegistry reqistry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();
            reqistry.register("*", new HttpFileHandler(docroot));

            // Set up the HTTP service
            this.httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, new NoConnectionReuseStrategy(), new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());
            this.httpService.setParams(this.params);
            this.httpService.setHandlerResolver(reqistry);
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Listening on port " + this.serversocket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("Point your browser to http://localhost:8088/tutorial/js/tutorial.html");

            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    // Set up HTTP connection
                    Socket socket = this.serversocket.accept();
                    DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
                    System.out.println("Incoming connection from " + socket.getInetAddress());
                    conn.bind(socket, this.params);

                    // Start worker thread
                    Thread t = new WorkerThread(this.httpService, conn);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    t.start();
                } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("I/O error initialising connection thread: " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        private final HttpService httpservice;
        private final HttpServerConnection conn;

        public WorkerThread(final HttpService httpservice, final HttpServerConnection conn) {
            super();
            this.httpservice = httpservice;
            this.conn = conn;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New connection thread");
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted() && this.conn.isOpen()) {
                    this.httpservice.handleRequest(this.conn, context);
                }
            } catch (ConnectionClosedException ex) {
                System.err.println("Client closed connection");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (HttpException ex) {
                System.err.println("Unrecoverable HTTP protocol violation: " + ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    this.conn.shutdown();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This Httpd server is amazing. It serves static pages (as GET) as well as Thrift processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use different ports.

For example, as in the tutorial examples, port 8088 can be bound to HTTP while port 9090 may be bound to socket transport.

If I'll want to use a different transport, I'll handle it in a different port.

<sub>** Amazing how I think of answers only after I submit the question. Is there a way to submit a question in my head to get faster to an answer? At least the community enjoys my brain blocks ;)</sub>

Comment: Without adding http processing, I don't see any other way.